# renegotiate_rate_limit

Tags: linux, unix, ssl

Does anyone know where and how to set this limit? This is regarding SSL/ TLS connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using OpenSSL and you want a renegotiation to happen after a certain number of bytes, you can use `BIO_set_ssl_renegotiate_bytes`.  If you want it to happen after a certain interval of time has elapsed, you can use `BIO_set_ssl_renegotiate_timeout`.

If, instead, you want to set an upper limit on how often renegotiation is allowed, I don't think OpenSSL has explicit support for that.  Instead, you might register an info callback with `BIO_set_info_callback` and then wait for `SSL_ST_RENEGOTIATE` notifications.  If you observe them at a rate greater than you want, take some action (eg close the connection).